# Merge data in an array if some keys are similar

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [Name] => Banana
            [Percentage] => 25
            [Sum] => 70
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [Name] => Banana
            [Percentage] => 25
            [Sum] => 168
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [Name] => Apple
            [Percentage] => 14
            [Sum] => 8
        )
    )
```

How can I merge the value only if keys `[Name]` and `[Percentage]` is similar to the other one in the array ?

For example, I search to have something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [Name] => Banana
        [Percentage] => 25
        [Sum] => 238
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [Name] => Apple
        [Percentage] => 14
        [Sum] => 8
    )
)
```

Here's what I tried:

```
foreach($myArray as $value){
    $Name = $value['Name'];
    if(isset($result[$Name]))
        $index = count($result[$Name]);
    else
        $index = 1;

    $result['Name'] = $Name;
    $result['Percentage'] = $value['Percentage'];
    $result['Sum'] += $value['Sum'];        
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I stated to make the condition for the `0` value but I do not know how to compare the values.

Comment: You'll need to show what you've tried and where you got stuck. This is not a free "please write my code" service!

Comment: @Jeff: please see my try. I'm new.

Comment: What do you mean by *"similar"*?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you currently have is that you are just kind of duplicating what you already have in your original array except you are throwing in a failed sum with `$result['Sum'] += $value['Sum'];`. See new example with notations below:

```
# Try setting a storing array
$new    =   array();
#loop through the array
foreach($array as $row) {
    # Check if you have already set the sum for this name type
    if(isset($new[$row['Name']]['Sum']))
        # Add new and stored value together
        $sum    =   $new[$row['Name']]['Sum'] + $row['Sum'];
    else
        # If not already set, set it
        $sum    =   $row['Sum'];
    # Start storing values into the new array. It's easiest to set the key
    # as the name value so it saves to unique keys
    $new[$row['Name']]  =   array(
        'Name'=>$row['Name'],
        'Percentage'=>$row['Percentage'],
        'Sum'=>$sum
    );
}

print_r(array_values($new));
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you want to do is traverse the array and compare the current item to the previous one, building an array of the unique items as you go.

If the `Name` and `Percentage` are equal between the current and previous item, then just add current item's sum to the previous one.  If not, then just add the current item to the new array.

This will work for you:

```
$newArray = Array();

foreach ($myArray as $currentItem) {

    if (isset($prevItem) && $currentItem['Name'] == $prevItem['Name'] && $currentItem['Percentage'] == $prevItem['Percentage']) {
        // append sum to previous item
        $prevItem['Sum'] += $currentItem['Sum'];
    } else {
        // add current item to array
        $newArray[] = $currentItem;
        $lastIndex = count($newArray) - 1;
        $prevItem = &$newArray[$lastIndex];
    }
}
```

> Note: this assumes the array is already sorted by name and percentage.